# Exception: no permission to access the requested document

Tags: google-apps-script

```
  try{
          var objSpreadsheetMast = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetIdMast);
        }catch(e){
            Browser.msgBox(e);
            Browser.msgBox("ファイルIDが有効であるか、あるいはアクセス権限があるかをご確認ください。");
            return;
        }
```

This code is the trigger call when the table changes and when the table changes ，Exception: no permission to access the requested document.But it works during debugging

Comment: You need to use installable trigger

Comment: Are you using a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) or [installable tigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)? Is the script [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) to the spreadsheet you're trying to open?

Comment: Using a simple trigger (when the table changes)

Answer (score 0):

To be allowed to use a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), you need to use a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> The script must be bound to a Google Sheets, Slides, Docs, or Forms
>   file, or else be an add-on that extends one of those applications.

Otherwise, you could use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.